# Data comparisson not working.

Tags: java

First half of code establishes if you're a man or woman. second half of code have answers depending on if man or woman. But when I enter "man" it still prints the code for woman. help please

```
   Scanner scan1 = new Scanner(System.in);        
   System.out.println("Are you a man or woman?");
   String user_inputs_sex = scan1.nextLine();
   String user_sex = user_inputs_sex;   

if (user_inputs_sex.equalsIgnoreCase("MAN")) 
     {
 user_sex = man;
     }
 else if (user_inputs_sex.equalsIgnoreCase("WOMAN")
     {
 user_sex = woman;
     }

System.out.println("Having a good day?");

if ((user_answer.equalsIgnoreCase("YES")) && (user_sex.equals(woman)))
    {                                                                 
    System.out.println("Glad to hear that ma'am");
    } 
 // when I enter "man" in the previous code it still prints out this code

    else if 
   ((user_answer.equalsIgnoreCase("NO")) && (user_sex.equals(woman))) 
    {
    System.out.println("Sorry to hear that ma'am");
    } 

 // here is same code as above but for a man
```

Comment: what is man  and woman value

Comment: You're not reading input after your follow up question.

Comment: The code you've provided doesn't give off the same errors that you claim it does in my IDE.  For instance, you're missing an extra paren on one of your else-if clauses.  Lastly, not only do you not include the code for the "man" portion, but you also lack definitions of `man`, `woman`, and `user_answer` in your code sample.  Until you fix those, it's going to be difficult for you to get an accurate answer.

Comment: Sorry about the code above it is missing stuff. The actual code is a lot larger so just tried to cut it down to the issue I was having but didn't do a good job of it.. Thanks to Arpan Sharma, got it working :).. And thanks for all the tips I'm noob at this